# TDE - Remove schema name and view name in column name

Tags: sql, xquery, xquery-sql, marklogic-10

I'm trying to create an simple SQL TDE template for XML documents in Marklogic DB.

Sample template:

```
<template xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde">
<context>/match</context>
<collections>
<collection>source1</collection>
</collections>
<rows>
<row>
<schema-name>soccer</schema-name>
<view-name>matches</view-name>
<columns>
<column>
<name>id</name>
<scalar-type>long</scalar-type>
<val>id</val>
</column>
<column>
<name>document</name>
<scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
<val>docUri</val>
</column>
<column>
<name>date</name>
<scalar-type>date</scalar-type>
<val>match-date</val>
</column>
<column>
<name>league</name>
<scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
<val>league</val>
</column>
</columns>
</row>
</rows>
</template>
```

I have inserted a sample document in the content database and the above template into Schemas database.

Now I'm trying to run a SQL query using XQuery as below:

```
xdmp:sql("select * from matches","map")
```

The above query returns the below response

| soccer.matches.id | soccer.matches.document | soccer.matches.date | soccer.matches.league |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567 | /soccer/match/1234567.xml | 2016-01-12 | Premier |

In json format it is,

```
[
{
"soccer.matches.id": 1234567, 
"soccer.matches.document": "/soccer/match/1234567.xml", 
"soccer.matches.date": "2016-01-12", 
"soccer.matches.league": "Premier"
}
]
```

In the above response the key name is returned as schema-name.view-name.column_name.E.g.,soccer.matches.id
But I need the key name to have only the column name.E.g., "id": 1234567

Could anyone please share the easiest way to achieve this in XQuery?

Answer (score 1):

You could probably se the names in the SQL statement using AS. You could always iterate over thr the results in a FLWOR statement to modify your results.

However, I suggest that you use the optic API and tune the results as you wish.

Using an `op:from-view` would be the suggested course of action. You could still use `op:from-sql()`. In both cases, experiment with the qualifier parameter including omitting it .  For the final results, you can use an `op:as()` with `op:select()` or `op:group-by()` to define exactly what you want.

Optic API reference: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/OpticAPI

Optic Functions:
https://docs.marklogic.com/op